# Angular Jasmine test, mock resolver for routes with guard Resolver

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an app with several lazy loaded modules, each with their own routing module. I'm looking to write some tests around each routing module that prevents a breaking change to their routes.

My plan was to export the routes from the routing module under test and import them to the RouterTestingModule of my spec and then mock out anything needed like resolvers, services etc.

**1)** For some reason in my example, it doesn't seem to be using the mocked resolver that I have created, I will get an error associated with trying to resolve the actual resolver.

**2)** Is this the correct approach? Most examples I've seen have tended to provide the routes in the test directly to RouterTestingModule but I can't see how that would prevent a breaking change to the actual routing module that I've simply copied it's routes into the test.

**account-routing.module.ts**

```
...
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account/:id',
        component: AccountDetailComponent,
        resolve: { campaign: AccountResolver },
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

**account-routing.module.spec.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MockAccountResolver implements Resolve<Account> {

  constructor() { }

  resolve() : Observable<Account>{

    let account = new Account();

    return of(account);
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
        declarations: [AccountDetailComponent],

        // also tried providers: [ { provide: AccountResolver, usevalue: new MockAccountResolver()}]
        providers: [ AccountResolver,  MockAccountResolver]
      });
  
      router = TestBed.get(Router);
      location = TestBed.get(Location);
  
      router.initialNavigation();
    });
    
   // Test 1
   it('navigate to "" redirects you to /', fakeAsync(() => {
      router.navigate([""]).then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/");
      });
    }));
    
    // Test 2
    it('navigate to ":id" redirects you to /1', fakeAsync(() => {
        router.navigate(["/account/1"]).then(() => {
          expect(location.path()).toBe("/account/1");
        });
    }));
```

Test 1 will pass, Test 2 will give an error:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AccountResolver -> AccountService -> ApiService -> ApiService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ApiService!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the provider line like this:

providers: [ { provide: AccountResolver, useClass: MockAccountResolver}]

and then adding a flush() statement to Test 2 and all is working